# is it possible at Promise.all add later a Promise to Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I working on a Project and I asked myself that it is feasible to start the `Promise.all` in Javascript and the task they do add further Promises to the Array and whether they are also be running or not?

Comment: Do you mean have a promise inside your promise array append another promise AFTER you call `Promise.all`?

Comment: Like:  var PromiseAr = []

function func1(){
new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
PromiseAr.push(func1())
});
}

func1();

Promise.all(PromiseAr).then(() => {
console.log("done");
})

Answer (score 1):

```
  const runAsyncFunctions = async () => {
  const users = await getUsers()

  if(users){
    Promise.all(
      users.map(async user => {
        const userId = await getIdFromUser(user)
        console.log(userId)

        const capitalizedId = await capitalizeIds(userId)
        console.log(capitalizedId)
      })
    )
      console.log(users)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var promise2 = 42;
var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
promise.all() work like this...
```

Comment: but what if you have an Array with Promises and add an Promise while the Promise.all are in work